# I have a 9v battery that is only needed to output power during night time/when the sun is down, how can i do this?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, circuit-design, low-power, solar-energy

My main question is, am I able to use a solar panel to only allow power flow when it is dark outside?/When the Solar panel isn't receiving any light? What would the circuit for that look like? In the same way a garden light works?

Comment: This question is not answerable.  You need to use the "edit" button to clarify what exactly you are trying to accomplish, or the question will soon be closed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple PNP circuit with a light dependent resistor. When the sun goes down the resistance of the LDR increases and the voltage drop across the LDR  forward biases the PNP transistor and illuminating the LED or whatever you like within the operating range of the transistor.

This should be a good start

[image: PNP circuit with LDR]

Here is another circuit that I found at
http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/SolarLight/SolarLight.html

[image]

Comment: would I also be able to add a 3v rechargeable battery that is connected to the solar panel?

Comment: Why make when U can buy these for a few bucks

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist for the fun of learning and enjoyment of building something with your own hands. Or you could just buy it

Comment: Yah buy it and make it bigger and better  by adding LEDs and bigger battery.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist sorry to bother, but could you throw a link my way of something that is like what is mentioned above?

Comment: Where do you live near? How big is Solar Panel [Watts, Voc]